# Turning off point for 1g acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, reference-frames, observers, time-dilation

Let's say I am on a ship accelerating with 1g. I want to keep the engine running for half a year ( to an observer from my point of origin ) but due to time dilation it would have to be sooner than half a year on the ship.. At what time - according to MY clock on the ship - do I have to turn the acceleration off?

Answer (score 4):

Let's do some math, shall we?

Let's call $t$ the time as measured from Earth, and let's say your engine is running with acceleration $a$ for $0 \le t \le T$. The proper time, that is, the time as measured by a clock on a ship, is given by $\tau = \int_0^T \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}\ dt$, where $v$ is the velocity as measured from Earth.

Newton's second law for relativity is

$$\frac{d}{dt} \frac{v}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} = a$$

which, after integrating and rearranging, gives

$$v(t) = \frac{at}{\sqrt{1+(at/c)^2}}.$$

Sticking this into the formula for $\tau$ and applying some integration magic, we get $\DeclareMathOperator\arcsinh{arcsinh} \tau = \frac{c}{a} \arcsinh (\frac{aT}{c})$. Plug in $a = 9.8\ \text{m}/\text{s}^2$, $c=3\times10^8\ \text{m}/\text{s}$, $T=0.5\ \text{years} = 1.5768\times 10^7\ \text{s}$ and we get $\tau \approx 1.5\times10^7\ \text{s} = 0.48\ \text{years}$. So accelerating at $1\ g$ for half a year only barely gets you into relativistic territory.